# Weird Favicon Issue with Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, favicon

Currently facing some issue with Firefox favicons.

Here is the links from my header :

```
<link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon-16x16.png">
```

And everything works like a charm on Chrome, Edge (and even Internet Explorer...) but things are getting weird as soon as I turn to Firefox.

The app is loading with blank favicon.
I figured out it's searching the favicon at the wrong locations, but I don't understand why.
[image]

As you can see, Firefox scanned all my icons, and they are duplicated in a `/img/icons/` folder.

But my code doesn't mention this path and I should just access the ones at the root. If I create the path, no problem, everything works fine. But I don't want that. I'd rather have every favicon in the same location

I tried to delete the `favicons.sqlite` and `places.sqlite`and tried to force refresh every cache, but nothing seems to change, Firefox still want to reach `/img/icons`.

Did someone already face this issue ? Any solution ?

Best Regards

Comment: Have you tried `rel="shortcut icon"`? It shouldn't matter but... (I assume `<%= BASE_URL %>` gets replaced by actual paths before it reaches the browser.)

Comment: Yep, I did try that Alvaro, but didn't make the cut. And indeed, `<%= BASE_URL %>` gets replaced to `/` in my case but could be anything.

Comment: Which version of Firefox are you on? Also, what do you mean by "gets replaced to `/`"? Shouldn't this be a fully qualified URL?

Comment: Version 78.0.2 on my side. 
No, you can serve relative content. Terrible practice when it comes to HTML only, but since I'm using VueJS it's packaging everything nice and tight to serve everything.

Comment: It seems related to the fact I'm developing a PWA